# Angular variable in component loops

Tags: angular, loops, variables, ngfor

Immediately after I change the value of a property inside the class of a component I am using in a loop, it resets to the original value.
This does not happen if I use the component alone, outside of any `*ngFor`.

For example, I have the following component:

```
export class CartProductComponent implements OnInit {
  loading = false;
    
  ...

  changeQuantity(change: number) {
    this.loading = true;
    ...
  }
}
```

that is used like this:

```
<app-cart-product *ngFor="let product of products" [product]="product"></app-cart-product>
```

Immediately after `changeQuantity` is called, the value resets to `false`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but it was fixed by doing as advised by Dima S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem you are experiencing is an expected behaviour, `ngForOf` will regenerate the view if it detects changes and the reference object its supplied with is not the same.
Try using [trackBy](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description)

Comment: Thank you. This was actually what I was looking for, something like Vue's `v-bind:key`, but I didn't know its equivalent in Angular.